# sort separator: braces and square brackets

Tags: text-processing, sort

I am using this command

```
cat acronyms.tex | sort -t{ -k1
```

to sort a file in which the format of the strings is like this

```
\newacronym{ex}{EX}{Expanded}
```

I want to sort by the content of the first pair of braces.
However, some lines are like this

```
\newacronym[a string]{ex2}{EX2}
```

The command I am using is not able to distinguish between `{` and `[`, and the result is that the second string is sorted before the first.

How can I make it distinguish `[` and `{`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `-k1` will make `sort` use the whole line as the sort key. This is not what you want.

I'm assuming that you'd like to use `ex` and `ex2` (as found within `{...}`) as the key.  To do this, specify `-k2` as the sort field.

This will pick up everything after the first `{` and use that as the key.

```
\newacronym{ex}{EX}{Expanded}
^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^^^
field 1     f2  f3  field 4

\newacronym[a string]{ex2}{EX2}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^ ^^^^
field 1               f2   f3
```

To *only* use the second field as the key (not the rest of the line), use `-k2,2`.

Testing:

```
$ sort -t '{' -k2,2 file
\newacronym[a string]{ex2}{EX2}
\newacronym{ex}{EX}{Expanded}
```

The line still comes out in the wrong order.  This is because `ex2}` sorts before `ex}` (`}` comes after `2` in the ASCII table, and I'm using the POSIX locale).

Trying again, but this time on Ubuntu with the `en_US.UTF-8` locale (should work on any glibc Linux and in most locales except the `C` or `POSIX` locales):

```
$ LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" sort -t '{' -k2,2 file
\newacronym{ex}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym[a string]{ex2}{EX2}
```

Depending on your locale settings, you may or may not have to add the `LC_COLLATE=...` bit.

---

Note that `sort` is a separate utility from the `bash` shell, and that it works the same way regardless of shell. This is therefore not a "`bash` sort" question, just a `sort` question.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some reason that you need to sort on *just* the contents of the first pair of braces, the simplest way is probably with a [decorate-sort-undecorate pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). I'm going to use [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html), but there are plenty of options to make this work in the shell:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^{]*{\([^}]*\)}\)/\2 \1/' < data|sort|cut -d' ' -f2-
```

The `sed` command replaces [everything up to the *end* of the first pair of braces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) with the contents of the braces, a space, and then the original string. That can be sorted as usual. I'm then `cut`ting the field I added at the start off again.

This will handle odd characters in the key fairly well, and uneven lengths, though spaces will be a problem, and escaped `\}` would be too. A different separator could be used if necessary.

---

If the data is:

```
\newacronym{A}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym{F}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym{D}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym{C}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym[abc]{B}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym{CD}{EX}{Expanded}
\newacronym[def]{E}{EX}{Expanded}
```

then the `sed` command results in:

```
A \newacronym{A}{EX}{Expanded}
F \newacronym{F}{EX}{Expanded}
D \newacronym{D}{EX}{Expanded}
C \newacronym{C}{EX}{Expanded}
B \newacronym[abc]{B}{EX}{Expanded}
CD \newacronym{CD}{EX}{Expanded}
E \newacronym[def]{E}{EX}{Expanded}
```

and the rest is straightforward.

Comment: Looks like the `[]` part of [newacronym](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary) can also contain braces, eg `\newacronym[longplural={Frames per Second}]{fpsLabel}{FPS}{Frame per Second}`

Comment: Yes, extra braces could be anywhere (even inside the first pair). At that point you just need to use a proper parser. There's no way to balance them otherwise.